# Puppet EXEC: execute part of code only after another part is executed

Tags: puppet, puppet-agent, exec

I have the following puppet code:

```
  exec { 'set mysql root password':
    user    => root,
    path   => "/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin",
    command => "/usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root password \'${root_pwd}\'",
    onlyif  => 'grep /etc/mysql_root_password_setup.cf -nrw -e \'0\'', 
  }

  exec { 'set mysql hostname password':
    user    => root,
    path   => "/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin",
    command => "/usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root -h ${::fqdn} password \'${root_pwd}\'",
    onlyif  => 'grep /etc/mysql_root_password_setup.cf -nrw -e \'0\'',
  }

  exec { 'Modify the Breadcrumb':
    user    => root,
    path   => "/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin",
    command => "echo 1 > /etc/mysql_root_password_setup.cf",
    onlyif  => 'grep /etc/mysql_root_password_setup.cf -nrw -e \'0\'',
  }
```

As you can see, I am running three exec command. The first one sets the Mysql password, the second does the same, the third one though, write 1 into a breadcrumb file `/etc/mysql_root_password_setup.cf`.

I want the the third exec to be executed only after the completion of first two exec.

How can I tell puppet to execute them in the order they are defined in the class file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Puppet's `require` parameter.

For example:

```
  exec { 'set mysql root password':
    ... 
  }

  exec { 'set mysql hostname password':
    require => Exec['set mysql root password'],
    ...
  }

  exec { 'Modify the Breadcrumb':
    require => Exec['set mysql hostname password'],
    ...
  }
```

Comment: thanks that was much easier than I though.